# Why shared ptr in vector not delete with reserve

Tags: c++

```
class A{
    public:
        A(){cout<<"constructor"<<endl;}
        ~A(){cout<<"destructor"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{   
    {
        //case 1
        vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vec;
        vec.reserve(1);
        vec[0] = std::make_shared<A>();
    }
    // Not destructor
    {
        //case 2
        vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> vec;
        vec.emplace_back(std::make_shared<A>());
    }
    // Called destructor
  return 0;
}
```

Why `vec` at end of life, the element within it not be deleted in case1.[result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r4DjAi4rJLsfKepc)

If we not reserve vector, but emplace back element to vec, it works.

Comment: `vec[0]` accesses the vector out of bounds and causes undefined behavior. You probably meant `resize` instead of `reserve`?

Comment: The `// case 1` is U.B. `std::vector::reserve()` is not sufficient. You had to use `resize(1)` instead (or `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` like in the `// case 2`).

Comment: You would see the same with a `vector<A>`.

Comment: `reserve(n)` just increases the buffer of `vec`, it does not increase the "number of managed elements" in the vector.

Comment: The [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) function sets the vectors *capacity*, while [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) sets it *size*. You have to learn the difference between a vectors capacity and its size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: I guess this is a typo and you meant to call `resize(1)` instead of `reserve(1)`, but I'd like to explain a bit, because I see how one could easily confuse the two functions.

---

`std::vector` has a [capactiy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) (the total slots that *can* be used) and a [size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) (the number of slots *actually used*).

[reserve()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) will increase the capacity, i.e. make room for more elements, but it will not increase the size. That's the job of [resize()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
vec.reserve(1); // capacity >= 1, size = 0!
```

Access to a vector is out of bounds if the index is >= the vector's size, irrespective of it's capacity, thus

```
vec[0] = std::make_shared<A>();
```

is out of bounds and leads to undefined behaviour. (index 0 >= size 0)